# React Native Pubish to expo

Tags: react-native, expo, gradlew

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO5sG.png

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
> [stderr]
> FAILURE:
> [stderr]
> Build failed with an exception.
> [stderr]

- What went wrong:
  [stderr]
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
  [stderr]

> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
> [stderr]

- Try:
  [stderr]

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> [stderr]
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> [stderr]
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> [stderr]

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  [stderr]
  BUILD FAILED in 3m 31s
  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
  You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
  See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
  8 actionable tasks: 8 executed
  Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched. The whole state of the virtual file system has been discarded. Reason: Could not query file systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No such file or directory)
  Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.

Comment: Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error. Please see logs for the "Run gradlew" phase.

Comment: Did you look into what the error said? "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build making it incompatible... you can use '--warning-mode-all' to show the deprecation warnings. What came back when you ran that? Are there any deprecated features you can update? What did the logs say when you checked them?